# Go.redirectro issue

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions, browser-hijacking

I have a hijacker  problem "Go.redirectro"
And it gave ma a horrible headache​
I tried registry editor and  take a file by file deep look at my drive  and uh god it took me long time

Look i am a computer guy and also i am an IT guy.

but this

This is a headache

I only managed to get only one weird script on regedit but guess what nothing.

I will be really thankful for any tips...like real tips not go google it :-!

Answer (score 1):

Checking your registry one by one is probably not the best idea, I understand your pain though, browser hijackers are a pain. I will assume that you already tried the following:

1. Checked your browser add-ons for any unrecognized extensions
2. Checked your programs for any unrecognized or suspicious activity
3. Installed RKill to kill any malicious processes
4. Ran a full scan with antivirus software
5. Scanned your PC with Malwarebytes, Hitman Pro, ADWCleaner, Zemana.
6. Used a third party application to attempt to clean your registries (Or in your case, did manually, I would still recommend trying a third party application)
7. Reset your browsers to default settings
8. Used browser specific clean up tools (Each browser has specific cleaner, like Chrome clean up tool)
9. Did all of the following steps in Windows "Safe mode with networking"

There are also adware/browser hijacker removal tools, like Bitdefender's adware removal tool. Nortons removal tool.

If yes, I am afraid, all of the conventional methods are exhausted at this point. And I too would like to know other possible solutions to this situations, if these do not help.

Comment: I did all the above steps.   Did't worked untill i used spyhunter it detected some registry keys at chrome extensions and thank god it worked...also sorry for not being obvious above there i was burning of fury 

Comment: It was "apple panda" hijacker to be accurate

Comment: Nice to hear, that you sorted your issues out. The main thing is that if conventional methods do not work, try a variety of them, I will be sure to look into Spyhunter's effectiveness in the future. Apple Panda is unheard for me, interesting. Thanks for your feedback!